# Spring Data, REST and ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

I wonder what is a good practice to create, document (swagger) and expose REST API involving many-to-many relationships. A simple example - `Student`, the 'owning' side:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Course> courses;

    ...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    ...
}
```

And `Course` (the students are not even exposed):

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

This results in 3 DB tables - students, courses and relation table (H2/hibernate). Let's get an existing student:

```
GET /api/students/1 HTTP/1.1
...

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Smith",
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Maths"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Java Programming"
    }
  ]
}
```

Fine. Now I would like to create a new student with POST request who is enrolled into two existing courses:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/students \
  -H 'postman-token: 706c8d0e-eca5-7bff-c557-3e199e8a0c17' \
  -d '{
  "name": "Peter Brown",
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Maths"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Java Programming"
    }
  ]
}'
```

On server side this may trigger a mapped method, e.g.:

```
@ApiOperation("Creates a new student.")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    value = "/api/students",
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {

    Student newStudent = studentRepository.save(student);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
            .path("/api/students/{id}").buildAndExpand(newStudent.getId())
            .toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(newStudent);
}
```

The student repository is a `CrudRepository`.

*Problem*: This will trigger the following error:

> detached entity passed to persist: xxx.domain.Course; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: xxx.domain.Course

Cause: the ID-s on the existing courses (they exist in DB) which makes them "detached". How should I handle these situations?

By creating a student and later updating it via REST? 
With a special logic into the controller? 
By changing the `CascadeType`?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I've treated the Student as DTO as suggested in the accepted answer and I've also introduced a PATCH/GET method for the courses.

Comment: My guess is, you have to persist the Student "empty" before and update afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should treat the `@RequestBody Student` as a dto (which it is actually) do not save it directly, better extract it, create the entities or retrieve them from the repository and build your final Student entity and save it to the database.

Comment: You mean that I should implement all this special processing withing the controller (or service)? First create a student then create or assign the courses, then return the final object within the response body?

Comment: exactly, but definetely in the service which only takes the dto object and return your student object, do not pollute the controller.

Comment: I'll play around and see if this looks nicely altogether (incl. the swagger documentation that will be generated at the end).

Comment: I added some skeleton to implement this logic, hope it helps!

Comment: The code is not really ok because if the new student is enrolled into existing classes the repo will throw the exception that I've quoted in my question. Rather it should first create an empty student and then update it with the existing (or new) courses.

Comment: You are right, I provide a better solution soon, if needed.